# Does killing an InnoDB process result in ROLLBACK of query?

Tags: mysql, kill

MySQL version 5.5.28

I accidentally ran an `UPDATE` query without a WHERE clause.

I then killed the process in MySQL using `kill 202085`.

Did that result in an automatic rollback? Or do I need to worry about a partially-executed query?

EDIT: My query was "SENDING DATA" according to `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

EDIT: Here is the query without the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE products t1,
`raw_table` t2
SET t1.`model` = t2.`model`
, t1.`sku` = CONCAT('ABC-',t2.`model`)
```

Without any `WHERE` clause, it's a mystery as to what the `UPDATE` would do, since I did not specify any relation.

After adding the `WHERE` clause, my query executed instantly and updated about 250 rows as expected.

```
WHERE t1.`model` = t2.`old_model`
AND t1.`vendor_id` = 53
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the database to see if rows got updated?  If you know how many instances of the new value should have been in the database before the update, you can run something like `select COUNT(*) from <table_name> where <col_name> = 'my_value';`.  If you have more instances of that value than you should have, then you can probably assume your change didn't get rolled back.

Comment: On a crash a roll back will be made upon restarting. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-recovery.html - The roll back will take up to 4 times longer than your acutal query. If the transaction has been committed before you killed mysqld it will not perform a roll back.

Comment: Pro-tip: When working on production data do not type the `;` until you've double or triple checked your query. Also if you don't have a good backup strategy, now's the time to implement one.

Comment: @tadman thanks, I did back up the whole database with mysqldump beforehand because I knew it was risky. But I'm glad the transaction rolled back because restoring could have taken awhile.

Comment: Good on you then. Just be careful. MySQL never, ever asks for confirmation, even on `DROP DATABASE mission_critical_system_full_of_never_backed_up_data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it rolls back.  But it depends on the stage of the query.  It won't rollback if it has committed the changes.  If you managed to kill the query before the operation, then it will rollback.

Comment: I am curious, are you assuming he is using transactions or does it matter?

Comment: Usually DML commands are run in autocommit mode.  They are committed as soon as the operation is completed.  If he is turning off autocommit, then  its easy to rollback manually too.

Comment: @bio_sprite This is how I've experienced InnoDB MVCC to work. If the command has not hit the commit phase it is rolled back. It can take substantial time to unwind a transaction though.

Comment: Yes exactly what I meant.  And yes it takes a substantial amount of time.  4x is an exaggeration though.

Comment: @bio_sprite I believe all InnoDB queries are implicitly transactions in order to maintain ACID compliance. The database should never be left in an intermediate state by a crash. But I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @ButtleButkus That's the general idea. I've also experienced rollbacks to take considerably longer than letting it run to completion, especially if there's heavy I/O contention.

Comment: by the way: My query was "SENDING DATA" according to `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

Comment: Could you share the exact query you were running?

Comment: @VishnuJ sure, I added it to the bottom of the question.